# Create-react-app no longer executes .map() after the build script compiles project

Tags: reactjs, compiler-errors, create-react-app, react-scripts, array.prototype.map

I have multiple react components populate lists of components with the .map() function that break the app only after the project is compiled with the react-script build.

Project Overview:
--backend: node, postgres, express
--frontend: react, redux, axios

The queries return in the form [{"k1":"v1"},{"k2":"v2"},...,{"kx":"kx"}] , except there are 8 key value pairs in each object of the array. I have traced the data objects all the way from the express api call to the component jsx with Array.isArray([dataObj]) and console.logs indicate that they are recognized as arrays, everything renders and works great.

then...

$npm run build
$server -s build

http://localhost:xxxx goes white after a flicker and the browser console alerts that 'x.map is not a function' and all my console logs of 'Array.isArray(dataObj)' report that these are not arrays and the application breaks.

Code Examples:
GitHub Gist URL = https://gist.github.com/GatesKennedy/21e24a6518d3bc4da45e3237af1f99ed

embed:

```html
<script src="https://gist.github.com/GatesKennedy/21e24a6518d3bc4da45e3237af1f99ed.js"></script>
```

Comment: What line does the exception happen on? When you log `dataObj` to the console, what does it show as?

Comment: @JoshHunt The error doesn't occur while running 'npm run start' which, for my setup executes 'react-scripts -r dotenv/config start'. Once I serve the frontend app locally with 'serve -s build' console shows 3-4 logs from independent processes running smoothly and immediately throws the 'TypeError: a.map() is not a function' and all associated logs declare that my objects are not arrays..

Comment: @JoshHunt This appears to have been an issue with CORS as I had deployed my backend and frontend deployed on seperate Heroku servers so there was no object to map through because it was being blocked from ever arriving at the frontend server.

Thank you for taking a look!